# Windows 10 IoT Core flashed SD card corrupted

Tags: windows-10

I was having troubles with my RPI running IoT Core, so when I checked the SD card I noticed its size was a mere 63 MB. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flashing process for W10 IoT Core will partition the drive (SD card) making the actual OS partition invisible in an explorer.

To restore the SD card run the following commands:

```
diskpart
list disk 
select disk [SD CARD DISK NUMBER]
clean
create partition primary
format fs=ntfs quick
```

Bottom line is that the issues you were having were not related to this SD cards state. There are certain types of SD cards that could cause issues, especially when they are slow.